# Data extraction in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the results from the excel data by using groupby function of Pandas. My code for that is:

```
results = df.groupby(['Test Result', 'Risk Rating']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

which is giving me the results in the form of this table:

```
Risk Rating  CRITICAL  HIGH  LOW  MEDIUM
Test Result
FAIL                8     0    9       4
PASS                0    13   23      37
SKIP                2     0    0       0
```

Now, I just want to get the result of all "FAIL" which should give me:

```
Risk Rating  CRITICAL  HIGH  LOW  MEDIUM
Test Result
FAIL                8     0    9       4
```

And, "FAIL" with just CRITICAL which should give me:

```
Risk Rating  CRITICAL
Test Result
FAIL                8
```

How can I achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use .loc

```
results.loc['Fail']
```

would return values of the index 'Fail'

```
results.loc['Fail', 'Critical']
```

would return values of the index 'Fail' for Column 'Critical'

you can pass list for multiple columns or index such has:

```
results.loc['Fail', ['Critical','HIGH']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) what return `Series` or scalar value:

```
df1 = df.ix['FAIL']
print (df1)
Risk Rating
CRITICAL    8
HIGH        0
LOW         9
MEDIUM      4
Name: FAIL, dtype: int64

df1 = df.ix['FAIL', 'CRITICAL']
print (df1)
8
```

More complicated is if need return `DataFrame` - use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html):

```
df1 = df.ix[df.index == 'FAIL', :]
print (df1)
Risk Rating  CRITICAL  HIGH  LOW  MEDIUM
Test Result                             
FAIL                8     0    9       4

df1 = df.ix[df.index == 'FAIL', ['CRITICAL']]
print (df1)
Risk Rating  CRITICAL
Test Result          
FAIL                8
```